# JavaScript: string.match regular expression help

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function that looks element id with certain patterns. So I have the following script:

```
if (f.elements[i].id.match(/DataList\[-\d{3}|\d{3}\]\.MemberId/)) {
  //do something
}
```

It should match elements with ids such as these:

```
DataList[-1].MemberId
DataList[-2].MemberId
```

And it does, however it also matches the following:

```
DataList[-1].FirstName
DataList[-2].FirstName
```

which I don't want.

**Could any guru take a look at the regular expression above and point out what is going wrong?**

Thanks,

Cullen

Comment: For the regex you posted to match the element names you listed, you'd need to change the `\d{3}` to `\d{1,3}`. See @Macarse's answer for a good explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to anchor your regex at the beginning with a `^` and at the end with a `$`, group your digit match and allow 1-3 digits instead of just 3.

```
if (f.elements[i].id.match(/^DataList\[(-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3})\]\.MemberId$/)) {
  //do something
}
```

The way you had it, it was matching anything containing "DataList[-123" or containing "123].MemberId".

A simpler overall regex that accomplishes the same thing is:

```
if (f.elements[i].id.match(/^DataList\[-?\d{1,3}\]\.MemberId$/)) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The or is saying:

```
DataList\[-\d{3} OR \d{3}\]\.MemberId/
```

This regex matches correctly:

```
DataList\[-?\d{1,3}\]\.MemberId
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion

```
   if (f.elements[i].id.match(/DataList\[-[0-9]{1,3}\]\.MemberId/)) {
  }
```

The {} determines how many #s you want to support so 1-3 would match upu to [999]